# How to create a reinforcement learning neural network to play flappy bird?

Tags: python, tensorflow, reinforcement-learning

I created a Flappy Bird clone using PyGame, and I want to teach a TensorFlow reinforcement learning neural network how to play it using the bird's y position, the bird's velocity, the distance to the next closest "pipe", and the y positions of the gap between pipes,top_y and bottom_y. So, 5 inputs to produce 1 output - a prediction of whether the bird should jump or not.

Sorry for this formatting - StackOverflow thought it was code.
    Here is my repo:
    https://github.com/joshuadargan/PenguinoFly.ai
    The key files for this problem are Game.py and NeuralNetwork.py:
    https://github.com/joshuadargan/PenguinoFly.ai/blob/master/NeuralNetwork.py
    https://github.com/joshuadargan/PenguinoFly.ai/blob/master/Game.py

I tried looking at a lot of different tutorials to figure things out, and I mostly based my neural network code from this:
https://towardsdatascience.com/reinforcement-learning-tutorial-part-3-basic-deep-q-learning-186164c3bf4

The tutorial talks about batching data, and that the input and output is two dimensional to allow for batching. I don't think batching the data would be possible. What changes should I make it to be able to train real-time with the 5 aforementioned variables and the 1 output.

The tutorial also mentions one_hot, which I didn't think applied to my situation. Should I keep it in there?

I have tried running it with the changes for my system (removing one_hot and adjusting the inputs and outputs), but I get this error:

```
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (5,) for Tensor 'Placeholder:0', 
which has shape '(?, 5)'
```

It starts from line 165 in Game.py where I call update. Then line 101 in 
NeuralNetwork.py where it calls train, which then calls get_Q on line 82, 
then the error is produced on line 54 in the get_Q function.

I am assuming that there are other errors in it too, but I can't bypass this error. I have tried to change the placeholder to be a rank 1 Tensor, but the hidden layer expects a rank 2 Tensor. I have also tried distributing the data across two arrays to satisfy it, but that didn't work either.

I expect to input the 5 aforementioned variables as the game's "state" and I expect a number between 0-1 representing the percentage that I should jump or not jump in that state.

What should I do to fix this problem, and what design suggestions do you have for my neural network?
Thank you!!